# split multiple strings in database

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

this is the first time I've tried something like this. I want those who understand to help.

I am trying to generate an ecommerce XML but in my database `['https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/v1/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a.jpg', 'https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/v1/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a1.jpg', 'https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a2.jpg', 'https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a3.jpg']` **In this way, I saved all the pictures of the product to my database. But I couldn't figure out how to distinguish ['this way', 'images'] from each other with the foreach structure.**

What I want is for him to take the pictures one by one. a [not whole]

For example:

image 1: here is the image url.
image 2: the second image url in the string.

How can I get it to be like?

PHP Code:

```
    <?php
$urunler = $baglanti->query("SELECT * FROM urunler LIMIT 50");
$urun = mysqli_fetch_array($urunler);
?>
    <url>
        <?php foreach ($urunler as $urun) 
        $urunlerx = $urun["image"];
          { ?>
        <urunler>
            <urunName><?php echo $urun["isim"]; ?></urunName>
            <anaKategori><?php echo $urun["anakategori"]; ?></anaKategori>
            <urunResim><?php echo $urun["image"]; ?></urunResim>
            <urunKodu><?php echo $urun["kodu"]; ?></urunKodu>
            <urunLink><?php echo $urun["link"]; ?></urunLink>
            <normalFiyat><?php echo $urun["normalfiyat"]; ?></normalFiyat>
            <urunEbat><?php echo $urun["ebatlar"]; ?></urunEbat>
            <urunOzellik><?php echo $urun["ozellik"]; ?></urunOzellik>
            <urunAciklama><?php echo $urun["aciklama"]; ?></urunAciklama> 
        </urunler>
        <?php } ?>
    </url>
    </urlset>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4EcO.png)

Comment: As you now know, it is a bad idea storing data like this, instead a parent child table structure makes processing this info SO MUCH EASIER

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the info, but I should be able to deal with it right now. Can you help me ?

Comment: `$urunler` is hopefully, if the query worked a MYSQL::RESULT object and therefore when used in the `mysqli_fetch_array($urunler);` fetches ONE of the 50 rows. BUT using it in the `foreach ($urunler as $urun) ` is nonsense and will not work.

Comment: Check out the [Manual Pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to find all strings between single quotes.

```php
$data = <<<'_DATA'
['https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/v1/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a.jpg', 'https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/v1/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a1.jpg', 'https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a2.jpg', 'https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a3.jpg']
_DATA;

$matches = [];
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $data, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $url) {
    echo "$url\n";
}
```

echoes

```
https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/v1/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a.jpg
https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/v1/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a1.jpg
https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a2.jpg
https://img-lcwaikiki.mncdn.com/mnresize/1024/-/pim/productimages/20211/5158707/l_20211-s1i862z8-hfm_a3.jpg
```